# CTE to build a list of departments and managers (hierarchical)

Tags: sql, recursion, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I need to generate a list of users that are managers, or managers of managers, for company departments.

I have two tables; one details the departments and one contains the manager hierarchy (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Manager](
[ManagerId] [int],
[ParentManagerId] [int])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
[DepartmentId] [int],
[ManagerId] [int])
```

Basically, I'm trying to build a CTE that will give me a list of DepartmentIds, together with all ManagerIds that are in the manager hierarchy for that department.

So... Say Manager 1 is the Manager for Department 1, and Manager 2 is Manager 1's Manager, and Manager 3 is Manager 2's Manager, I'd like to see:

```
DepartmentId, ManagerId
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
```

Basically, managers are able to deal with all of their sub-manager's departments.

Building the CTE to return the Manager hierarchy was fairly simple, but I'm struggling to inject the Departments in there:

```
WITH DepartmentManagers
AS
(
    SELECT      ManagerId,
                ParentManagerId,
                0 AS Depth
    From        Manager

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      Manager.ManagerId,
                Manager.ParentManagerId,
                DepartmentManagers.Depth + 1 AS Depth
    FROM        Manager
    INNER JOIN  DepartmentManagers
                ON DepartmentManagers.ManagerId = Manager.ParentManagerId
)
```

I need a list of all Departments together with all related Managers.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your anchor query:

```
WITH    DepartmentManagers
        AS
        (
        SELECT  d.DepartmentID,
                d.ManagerId,
                m.ParentManagerId
                0 AS Depth
        FROM    Department d
        JOIN    Manager m
        ON      m.ManagerID = d.managerID
        WHERE   DepartmentID = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  d.DepartementID,
                m.ManagerId,
                m.ParentManagerId,
                d.Depth + 1
        FROM    DepartmentManagers d
        JOIN    Manager m
        ON      m.ManagerId = d.ParentManagerID
        )
```

Comment: Sorry - I was a little unclear on exactly what I need the results to contain. I want to list all departments with all of their managers - this will form the basis of a view.

Thanks

Comment: Ah. This doesn't appear to work where a manager is a manager of more than 1 department. I'm discovering that the data I'm dealing with is pretty bad: a manager can also be their own manager!? I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: @Milky: could you please express the problem more definitely than "doesn't appear to work?" The best way would be to update your post with a sample recordset and desired results.

Comment: I've marked your response as the answer. To be fair to you, you've answered my original question perfectly. It's just that, after digging deeper, the data is a little more complex. It looks like I'll need to flesh out the manager hierarchy stuff a little more.

Cheers for your help!